# prevent clustered index insert operator on unqualified indexed view

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know a workaround for this?  Essentially, the stored procedure forces an insert operator against the indexed view, even though the rows don't qualify.  As a result, there is a cast error.  However, for ad hocs, sql correctly eliminates the view from consideration.

Consider the following schema:

```
create table testdata (
    testid int identity(1,1) primary key
  , kind varchar(50)
  , data nvarchar(4000))
go
create view integer_testdata with schemabinding
as
select cast(a.data as int) data, a.kind, a.testid
  from dbo.testdata a
 where a.kind = 'integer'
go
create unique clustered index cl_intdata on integer_testdata(data)
go
create procedure insert_testdata
(
    @kind varchar(50)
  , @data nvarchar(4000)
)
as
begin
  insert into testdata (kind, data) values (@kind, @data)
end
go
```

These all work:

```
insert into testdata (kind, data) values ('integer', '1234');
insert into testdata (kind, data) values ('integer', 12345);
insert into testdata (kind, data) values ('noninteger', 'noninteger');
exec insert_testdata @kind = 'integer', @data = '123456';
exec insert_testdata @kind = 'integer', @data = 1234567;
```

This fails:

```
exec insert_testdata @kind = 'noninteger', @data = 'noninteger';
```

A comparison of the "estimated execution plans":

`insert into testdata (kind, data) values ('noninteger', 'noninteger')`:
[image]

`exec insert_testdata @kind = 'noninteger', @data = 'noninteger'`:
[image]

Comment: Any notable differences between the ad hoc and cached stored proc plan per chance?

Comment: yes, when you execute ad hoc, you don't get any operators against the indexed view... I think sql is smart enough to see there is a filter on the view and eliminate it from consideration (this elimination does not happen in the proc)

Comment: Not in a position to test but does adding `option (recompile)` help?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what problem are you trying to solve.  This smells like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @MartinSmith no, that was one of my first thoughts, but it did not change the behavior

Comment: @MaxVernon I'm working with an existing data structure and need a fast lookup on unique integer values stored in subset of nvarchar(4000)'s, a filter on another column defines that subset of rows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for providing a full script to recreate the problem.

I tested it with SQL Server 2014 Express.

When I add `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` it works:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[insert_testdata]
(
    @kind varchar(50)
  , @data nvarchar(4000)
)
as
begin
  insert into testdata (kind, data) 
  values (@kind, @data)
  OPTION(RECOMPILE);
end
```

When I run this in SSMS:

```
exec insert_testdata @kind = 'noninteger', @data = 'noninteger';
```

I get this message:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
```

and a row is added to the table.

What version of SQL Server are you using? I vaguely remember that in versions before 2008 this `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` behaved a bit differently.

---

> I'm working with an existing data structure and need a fast lookup on
>   unique integer values stored in subset of nvarchar(4000)'s, a filter
>   on another column defines that subset of rows.

In this case it may be better to use [filtered index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280372.aspx) instead of indexed view:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_DataFiltered] ON [dbo].[testdata]
(
    [data] ASC
)
WHERE ([kind]='integer')
```

Optimizer should use this index when the `WHERE` filter of the query matches exactly the `WHERE` clause of the index.

Yes, here index is on `nvarchar` column which may be not the best thing, especially if you join this table with an `int` column of another table, or try to filter values in this column using `int` values.

---

Another variant that comes to mind is [persisted computed column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms188300.aspx) that converts `nvarchar` to `int`. In essence it is very similar to your view, but the persisted `nvarchar` values that are converted into `int` are stored with the same table, not in a separate object.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testdata](
    [testid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [kind] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [data] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [int_data]  AS (case when [kind]='integer' then CONVERT([int],[data]) end) PERSISTED,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [testid] ASC
))


CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_int_data_filtered] ON [dbo].[testdata]
(
    [int_data] ASC
)
WHERE ([kind]='integer')
```

With this set up I tried to use your original stored procedure to insert rows and it worked even without `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`.

---

Actually, it seems that the main reason why the above persisted column works is that I use `CASE`. If I add `CASE` to the definition of your view, the stored procedure works without `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`.

```
create view integer_testdata2 with schemabinding
as
select 
    case when a.kind='integer' then CONVERT(int, a.data) end as data
    , a.kind, a.testid
from dbo.testdata a
where a.kind = 'integer'
go
```

Comment: I'm not sure the filtered index will work well because the column width is 4000 (well above the limit of 900).  I had not thought of using a query hint option recompile... I was applying recompile to the entire procedure.  Your suggestion works for all my test cases!  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, filtered index on original column may be not very useful. I added another variant with persisted computed column.

Comment: I love the persisted computed column option... that strikes me as the correct solution